# Python 3 imports: convention vs performance?

Tags: python-3.x, import, syntax, module

Is there any benefit to saying:

```
import turtle
```

vs:

```
from turtle import x
```

Am I saving memory? Also, why if I say:

```
from tkinter import *
```

do I still have to say:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

in order to use filedialog? Coming from Java where * means import everything from x library, I find myself confused.

Comment: No, you are not really saving much memory. `from <module> import *` only dictates what names are bound in the current module (into which those names are added).

Comment: See ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403)

Comment: Importing a module *always loads the whole module*, if it wasn't yet loaded; all that differs between the different forms you show here is control over what names you added from the imported module; `turtle`, or all names *in* `turtle`, or all names in `tkinter` or only the name `filedialog`.

Comment: Ah I see okay great thank you!